# SQL Server Full-text contains case in-sensitive Issue

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

We have created `full-text` `index` on a `table` named `TEST`

We are using `Contains` search, which is case in-sensitive by behavior. But surprisingly it is not for word breaker characters.

Let's take an example:-

```
DROP TABLE TEST
GO
GO
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    EMP_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    EMP_NAME varchar(250)
)

GO
TRUNCATE TABLE TEST
INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT 'M.SC' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M.Sc' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M.sc' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M.sC' UNION ALL
SELECT 'm.SC' UNION ALL
SELECT 'm.Sc' UNION ALL
SELECT 'm.sc' UNION ALL
SELECT 'm.sC'
```

Now let's query the data

```
select COUNT(1) from TEST where contains(EMP_NAME, 'm.sc') -- will return only single record named 'm.sc'
select COUNT(1) from TEST where contains(EMP_NAME, 'm.Sc') -- will return all the records except 'm.sc'
```

First query will return single record, but second query will return 7 records.

However, I can do this to get all the results.

```
select COUNT(1) from TEST where contains(EMP_NAME, '("m.Sc" OR m.sc)')
```

But, thinking that there should be any other way as well.

Comment: Could this be a collation issue? I get 7 rows for both SELECT statements, in each case excluding M.Sc  - but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @JanineRawnsley , you can set your `STOPLIST` `OFF`

Comment: I did - I mean that's the first thing I tried. Strange that we're getting different (and both incorrect) results.

Comment: @JanineRawnsley the `collation` is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` on `TEST` table. What is your `collation`?

Comment: Latin1_General_CI_AS